# Blender Render to Cycles Render

Tags: python, cycles-render-engine, blender-internal-render-engine

I have a full made object in Blender 2.79b, but I put all textures in Blender Render, I need it in Cycles Render. I have tried the Python code that I found online, but it didn't work. I didn't put materials through nodes but with UV Editing, so maybe that is the reason that it didn't work. Is there another way except starting over?

Comment: Hi @user84021, this question doesn't really provide enough information to allow it to be answered.  Textures a and UV maps are independent of the render engine, so you don't need to start over, but some experimenting with Cycles and learning nodes would be beneficial.

Comment: hi @Merlin. I know it's better with nodes but I didn't have time to learn it, and this was just the faster option.
I'm applying textures the way that it is shown in this video (first part in Blender Render): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6gRUUeFteQg

Comment: Cycles uses nodes, if you want to use cycles, you need to learn them.  This site is not a magic bullet for that I'm afraid.  The more effort you put into your question, the more likely you are to attract the answer you want.

Comment: Technically it is possible to use Cycles without nodes. Nodes are just representing the connections, but you can make them from the Properties Editor. It's just inconvenient and there is probably no difference in the amount of time needed to learn it. Saying 'I don't have time to learn nodes' is the same as saying you don't have time to learn Cycles, but you want to use it anyway. That is not how it works. You will need to learn it in order to use it. It's best to accept that from the beginning. Converting materials between different render engines usually cannot be automatic.